# Not sure why date-picker widget isn't working, also don't know why the id selector isn't auto filling results field

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

I'm trying to write a very simple calculator for rent arrears. I have looked at and followed the codecademy tutorial about date pickers but still can't see where I'm going wrong!

I Also tried to get the calculator to autofill the results section as soon as the user fills in any details by giving the results fields id's but this isn't working either and I'm not sure why!

Any tips/hints would be greatly appreciated. I will post my HTML code and my JS below, and here is a link to my JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezjp20/ak5hexnx/

HTML:

```
 <div class='tablerow'>
    <table width="700">
        <tr>
             <h2>Rent Arrears Calculator</h2>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="350" align="left"> <b>Amount of Rent Due Per Calendar Month</b> 
            </th>
            <th width="350" align="left">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="50" data-bind="rentAmount" placeholder="Amount">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="350" align="left"><b>Due Date of First Missing Payment</b>

            </th>
            <th width="350" align="left">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="date1" class="form-control date" size="150" data-bind="dueDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="350" align="left"><b>Arrears calculated Until</b>

            </th>
            <th width="350" align="left">
                <input type="text" id="date2" class="form-control date" size="150" data-bind="untilDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
    <p></p>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>

         <h2 class="title" width="700px">Results</h2>

     </tr>
     <tr class="results">
        <th class="tablecolumn" align="left" width="350px">Due Date of 1st Missed Payment</th>
        <th align="left" id="dueDateFirstMissed" />DD/MM/YYYY</tr>
    <tr class="results">
        <th class="tablecolumn" align="left" width="350px">Date Calculated Until</th>
        <th align="left" id="untilDateCalculate" />DD/MM/YYYY
        <tr class="results">
            <th class="tablecolumn" align="left" width="350px">Number of Days Late</th>
            <th align="left" id="numberDays" />0</tr>
        <tr class="results">
            <th class="tablecolumn" align="left" width="350px">Amount Due</th>
            <th align="left" id="amountDue" />£0.00</tr>
        <tr class="results">
            <th class="tablecolumn" align="left" width="350px">Daily Rate</th>
            <th align="left" id="dailyRate" />£0.00</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
 var t;
 var workings = function (options) {

function getDueDateFirst() {
    return (options.dueDate);
}

function getDateCalculatedUntil() {
    return (options.untilDate);
}

function getNumberDays() {
    return ((((options.dueDate).val()) - ((options.untilDate).val())) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}

function getDailyRate() {
    return (((options.rentAmount).val()) * (12 / 365));
}

function getAmountDue() {
    return (getDailyRate()) * (getNumberDays());
}
return {
    dueDateFirst: getDueDateFirst(),
    dateCalculatedUntil: getDateCalculatedUntil(),
    numberDays: getNumberDays(),
    dailyRate: getDailyRate(),
    amountDue: getAmountDue()
};
};

var dataBind = function () {

var config = {
    dueDate: new Date($('*[data-bind="dueDate"]').val()),
    untilDate: new Date($('*[data-bind="untilDate"]').val()),
    rentAmount: $('*[data-bind="rentAmount"]').val()
};
t = new workings(config);

$("#dueDateFirstMissed").innerhtml(t.dueDateFirst);
$("#untilDateCalculate").html((t.dateCalculatedUntil));
$("#numberDays").html(t.numberDays.toFixed(0));
$("#amountDue").html(t.amountDue.toFixed(2));
$("#dailyRate").html((t.dailyRate).toFixed(2));
};
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#date1').datepicker();
$('#date2').datepicker();
});

$(".date1").datepicker({

}).on("changeDate", function (e) {
dataBind();
});

$(".date2").datepicker({

}).on("changeDate", function (e) {
dataBind();
});

$(document).on("keyup", "table input", function () {
dataBind();
});
```

Comment: You are not including jQuery library

Comment: You forgot to add JQuery qnd JQuery UI to your JSFiddle. [Here it is...](https://jsfiddle.net/ak5hexnx/16/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6pj1oq6p/1/

Comment: Thanks so much!! How did you add them in??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the javascript code now, its working. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak5hexnx/19/)

```
var t;
var workings = function (options) {

    function getDueDateFirst() {
        return options.dueDate;
    }

    function getDateCalculatedUntil() {
        return options.untilDate;
    }

    function getNumberDays() {
       //edited this line as it was giving negative value
       //changed options.unitlDate.val() to option.unitlDate similarly for options.dueDate
        return (options.untilDate - options.dueDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }

    function getDailyRate() {
        return options.rentAmount * (12 / 365);
    }

    function getAmountDue() {
        return getDailyRate() * getNumberDays();
    }
    return {
        dueDateFirst: getDueDateFirst(),
        dateCalculatedUntil: getDateCalculatedUntil(),
        numberDays: getNumberDays(),
        dailyRate: getDailyRate(),
        amountDue: getAmountDue()
    };
};

var dataBind = function () {

    var config = {
        dueDate: new Date($('#date1').val()),
        untilDate: new Date($('#date2').val()),
        rentAmount: $('[data-bind="rentAmount"]').val()
    };
    t = new workings(config);

    $("#dueDateFirstMissed").html(t.dueDateFirst);
    $("#untilDateCalculate").html((t.dateCalculatedUntil));
    $("#numberDays").html(t.numberDays.toFixed(0));
    $("#amountDue").html(t.amountDue.toFixed(2));
    $("#dailyRate").html((t.dailyRate).toFixed(2));
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date1").datepicker({
    //you were calling on event on a class 'date1' where as it was an id
    //changed changeDate to change
    }).on("change", function (e) {
        dataBind();
    });

    //you were calling on event on a class 'date2' where as it was an id
    $("#date2").datepicker({
    //changed changeDate to change
    }).on("change", function (e) {
        dataBind();
    });

});


//changed "keyup" to "change" event
$(document).on("change", "table input", function () {
    dataBind();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! What did you change?

Comment: @Zehrazjp20, I have added comments in the above code where ever I have changed the code.

Comment: happy that it helped you.. @Zehrazjp20

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery.
jQuery UI needs it

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks so much, date picker is now working! just need to get the actual calculations to work now lol

Comment: Not really sure how this is not an answer, not including jQuery is the reason for both problems in the title question